# python2.7 create array in loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, fits

I would like to create a new variable in a loop with an index in which I write a 2d matrix of data. Something like this:

```
import numpy
DARK = []
a = []
for i in range(0,3):
    # create 3d numpy array
    d = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    a.append(d)
    stack = numpy.array(a)
    # write it into the actual variable (here is the problem)
    DARK[i] = numpy.median(stack)
```

I tried an approach with DARK.append but that gave me an list index out of range error.

Comment: How is DARK initialized?

Comment: What is Dark supposed to be? An empty array maybe?

Comment: Show the code which gave an error, and the traceback error message in full?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question.

Comment: DARK is the data from a bunch of fits files I read in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of trying I found the answer myself. Thanks for the great help guys...

```
import numpy
DARK = []
a = []
stack = []
for i in range(0,3):
    # create 3d numpy array
    d = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    a.append(d)
    stack.append(numpy.array(a))
    # write it into the actual variable
    DARK.append(numpy.array(numpy.median(stack[i], 0)))
```